# quisiera filtrar una datatable pero en forma inversa

Tags: c#, datatable

he encontrado estos ejemplos:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

dt es un DataTable y tiene datos, pero hay algunos datos que son nulos, quisiera filtrar las rows que contengan dichos datos nulos.

numero es una de las columnas.

yo quisiera filtrar y quedarme con todas las filas del datatable que no sean null

```
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "numero <> 'null Column'"; (1)
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

pero me da este error cuando intenta ejecutar (1)

Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.EvaluateException' en System.Data.dll

Información adicional: No se puede realizar la operación '<>' en System.Double y System.String.

existe la forma de filtrar y quedarme con las filas que son null

```
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[numero] is null";
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

pero yo quiero lo contrario, o sea NO quedarme con las que son null

Comment: ¿haz intentado `[numero] is not null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías utilizar IS NOT NULL en lugar de IS NULL:

```
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "numero IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: gracias, funciona tanto en minusculas como en mayusculas